# com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

Tags: android, flutter

I am using two packages in my flutter application

[flutter_jailbreak_detection](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_jailbreak_detection)

[flutter_root_jailbreak](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_root_jailbreak)

for android both using same native `implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.1.0'` dependency
so i am not able to run the application on android platform because native package class duplication.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDevDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.scottyab.rootbeer.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-rootbeer-0.1.0-runtime (com.github.scottyab:rootbeer:0.1.0) and jetified-rootbeer-lib-0.1.0-runtime (com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.scottyab.rootbeer.Const found in modules jetified-rootbeer-0.1.0-runtime (com.github.scottyab:rootbeer:0.1.0) and jetified-rootbeer-lib-0.1.0-runtime (com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.scottyab.rootbeer.RootBeer found in modules jetified-rootbeer-0.1.0-runtime (com.github.scottyab:rootbeer:0.1.0) and jetified-rootbeer-lib-0.1.0-runtime (com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.scottyab.rootbeer.RootBeerNative found in modules jetified-rootbeer-0.1.0-runtime (com.github.scottyab:rootbeer:0.1.0) and jetified-rootbeer-lib-0.1.0-runtime (com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.scottyab.rootbeer.util.QLog found in modules jetified-rootbeer-0.1.0-runtime (com.github.scottyab:rootbeer:0.1.0) and jetified-rootbeer-lib-0.1.0-runtime (com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.scottyab.rootbeer.util.Utils found in modules jetified-rootbeer-0.1.0-runtime (com.github.scottyab:rootbeer:0.1.0) and jetified-rootbeer-lib-0.1.0-runtime (com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.1.0)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

as per documentation i also tried to exclude / grouping same package in app level build gradle file using with bellow code but still not able to runrun the app.

```
implementation ('com.example.library:library:1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.scottyab', module: 'rootbeer'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the RootBeer library in an Android project, open the android/app/build.gradle file, and try adding the following block to exclude the conflicting classes

```html
android {
    ...
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude group: 'com.scottyab', module: 'rootbeer-lib'
        }
    }
}
```